# Ultra low-latency in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04, matlab, mesa

I should run a visual experiment project with Matlab or Python in which the time resolution is dramatically important! that's why I shift to Linux and use the low-latency kernel in ubuntu. but I thought there is an ultra-low-latency or something like that in Linux Nvidia settings, same as a thing in 3D acceleration in Nvidia control panel windows.

Is there any way that enables Nvidia ultra-low latency in ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: What kind of Nvidia card do you have? Also make sure Additional Drivers are installed by going to Search bar > Additional Drivers. Doing a Software Update might help too. You can verify Nvidia setting by going to Terminal and then typing in nvidia-settings

Comment: My setup is Nvidia 1080 ti GPU, 240hz monitor, and ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 5):

You may not need that setting and it may be worth knowing what "low latency" means in detail to see how it adjust to whatever you need to test:

## Kernel "low latency"

When the kernel is built in low latency, it ticks at 1000hz

This means the kernel will preempt processes 1000 times per second as opposed to 100-200 times (or Windows' maximum 1000hz when [timeBeginPeriod(1)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod) is called)

The details are explained in [another post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/553993/350793) but basically it boils down to context switching happening more often which means sleeping threads can wake faster and things that need to be processed ASAP (like an audio server) are woken up earlier.

It basically makes the kernel check on each process "are you done yet?" much more often.

The cost is higher CPU overhead from waking up so often, and horrible energy efficiency (btw you should keep your CPU governor in performance for stable readings)

## Graphics "low latency"

Low latency in graphics is defined as "the time it takes for an input, like a keyboard stroke, to appear on screen".

### VSync off

When VSync is off, you already get the lowest latency; because if graphics are rendered at 300 fps on a 60hz monitor; it will be shown at 300hz and be displayed immediately even if the monitor is still displaying the previous frame, which causes [visible tearing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ENCV4xUjj0) as two or more frames overlap.

There is a limit on how fast it can be shown on screen even if VSync is off, which will be limited by the monitor's pixel response (usually 5ms) and other HW limits.

NVIDIA settings don't matter here, **because you're already getting the lowest possible latency**.

### VSync On

VSync waits for the VBlank interval in order to swap the image. This means you get a perfect picture on the monitor.

However most monitors display at 60hz (unless you buy e.g. a 240hz one).

If GPU was still working on a frame when the VBlank interval came, it needs to wait another 16.666ms (I'll truncate to 16ms for brevity) so it can be displayed. This is known as "missing" the VBlank interval, and thus latency is added.

Another problem is that if your app takes e.g. 2ms to process and started right after VBlank, now you need to sit idle for 14ms before it can be displayed on screen.

By the time it gets displayed on screen, the input being shown was gathered at least 16ms ago or more (assuming your app started right after VBlank, if it started 8ms after VBlank, then it took you 2ms to process, 6ms of idle, and the inputs are at least 8ms old or more).

This gets exacerbated with triple buffering which may add *up to* a whole frame of latency (16ms!)

NVIDIA's low latency option is a combination of techniques and hacks (often tuned for the popular games, which means it may not always work in your particular application) that when enabled:

1. Double Buffering is favoured over Triple Buffer. I believe this option is already available on NVIDIA settings separately.
2. It **forces the app to sleep**. We said in your example that you take 2ms to process (I'm making the numbers up, it's an example). If this is stable, the ideal is to sleep for roughly 13ms after vblank, gather your buffered input (e.g. keyboard, sensors, etc), process everything in 2ms, and you still have 1ms of spare for overhead and display on screen. Hence the image displayed on screen shows the inputs roughly gathered 3ms ago with no tearing (+5ms of pixel response so it's probably 8ms ago).

   - The tricky part is knowing when vblank happens
   - The even more tricky part is estimating how long you will take to process inputs. It's rarely a perfect 2ms and there may be noise and jitter (OS allocations will destroy you). If you overestimate you'll miss the next Vblank and will have to wait another 16ms
   - For more info see [Controller to Display Latency in Call of Duty](https://www.gdcvault.com/play/1026327/Controller-to-Display-Latency-in)

## What this means

1. I didn't mention this, but Python is a terrible choice for low latency stuff. It's an interpreted language with lots of memory allocations which causes a lot of jitter. That's why audio servers are written in C (and not just any C, you have to adhere to some rules like avoid most mutex or use them sparingly, do not call malloc, etc). That depends on how extreme the low latency is. Having a strict 3ms requirement isn't the same as a loose 20ms requirement.
2. You can turn off Triple Buffering in NVIDIA settings.
3. If you don't care about tearing, turn VSync off. You're done.
4. You can solve all the next problems with money, by buying a 240hz monitor. You're done.
5. If you care about tearing and can't buy a 240hz monitor, prefer using Vulkan (*or an engine that uses Vulkan* and exposes to you settings such as triple/double buffer and mailbox presentation) which needs more expert knowledge but gives you more tools to know when VBlank happens and how presentation happens (e.g. FIFO vs Mailbox presentation; I won't go into detail but you'll want to use Mailbox). You are also in full control of whether Double or Triple buffer is used.
6. Take measurements and test how long you need to `sleep()` on a given machine. Once you found the sweet spot this may be 'good enough'.
7. Ideally, use DRM instead of Xorg or Wayland interface (this is VERY advanced) to control the screen directly.
8. If you only care about generating a report and analyzing/crunching numbers later; and displaying on screen in real time as fast as possible is not necessary; then this entire section has been a waste of time because "NVIDIA low latency" settings won't affect your readings; it only controls how old the data was when it's displayed on screen.

## Other misc

Set CPU governor to performance for stable readings. Disable the GPU's power saving for the same reason (how to do that varies on vendor / driver).

[Fighting Latency on Call of Duty: Black Ops III](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtLHLfNpu84) is a recommended reading on how they setup a GoPro camera to identify sources of latency and fix it; even though most of the talk is oriented towards multiplayer network latency (which is in the order of 30-200ms)

Ultimately low latency is a deep topic and I'm afraid a single toggle may or may not do what you want; depending on what you need.

Comment: I'm very appreciative of this article, it was really useful. actually, I should use the EEG to scan brain dynamics and send triggers from my PC to that at the same time. so I think the low-latency kernel is necessary in this case.
I use to be working with windows, but now to the suggestion of the Psychtoolbox website for better & precision performance installed Linux. 
I've just had doubts about using a Linux due to the Nvidia card which may not the ideal thing.
So, Do you suggest using Linux in this case?

Comment: Windows w/ `timeBeginPeriod(1)` can have similar levels of low latency. If this is prototype/hobby and you feel more familiar w/ Windows then just go with that. If you're looking into long term or medical/industrial application; Linux + FOSS friendly GPUs (AMD, Intel) will save you from vendor lock-in. MS keeps breaking Windows 10 in weird ways, is troublesome if you don't have access to LTSC, and NV stops supporting GPUs after a while or wants you to have all NV. NV in general doesn't play well along with Linux except to support what their Quadro clients need.

Comment: In short: If it's a prototype, it's ok to start with Windows but don't actively preclude Linux support. If the prototype is a success, start thinking into securing funding to minimize your reliance on external dependencies you can't control which are all risks; and that often leads you to Linux + FOSS friendly HW.